# Call my smart contract method which should be reverted ,but the transaction is still be send and mined

Tags: go-ethereum

When i interact with my contract by web3,metamask[image] and ganache-cli everything's going well .eg 
i called the contract method with inccorect parameters ,then the error was throwed.[image]

But when i deploy my contract on my testNetwork(go ethereum)and call  whichever method with inccorect parameters,only warning throwed and the transaction can still be send and mined  [image]

Comment: Totally unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct. The execution of the transaction reverted.

The transaction was sent successfully. After that a miner picked it up and started executing the instructions in the transaction against the contract code. At that point the code execution encountered a `revert` condition and an error was thrown.

It's only a matter of how the revert error is displayed. The path to the error is the same: it needs to be mined (executed) in order for the error to manifest itself. So the transaction succeeds but its execution fails. In both cases the transaction is also mined.